# Cordova save Image in Gallery

Tags: android, cordova, gallery

I am developing an application with Apache Cordova and recognized that images the app takes aren't displayed in the gallery

```
 window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSys) {
        fileSys.root.getDirectory(_ImageFolder,
                { create: true, exclusive: false },
                function (directory) {
                    entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName, successMove, resOnError);
                },
        resOnError);
```

The Images are saved to

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.cordova.myApp/cache/1432130422117.jpg
```

so is there a Way to show them in the gallery if the device? Maybe even in an own folder?